# Google search to include all morphological inflections of a lexeme

Tags: finnish, research-techniques

Is there a way for Google search to include all inflections of a lexeme in the results?
I am thinking specifically of languages other than English.

Here is an example of what I have in mind.

I am interested in sample sentences of the Finnish word "hahmottaa" (To grasp, to understand).

Since Finnish is an agglutinative language, the lexeme consists a dozen or more words. E.g. "hahmotamme", "hahmotimme" etc. I want the search to include all of them.

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding all inflections requires wildcards, and Google's support for wildcards appears to be limited. According to the article [What is a Google Wildcard Search?](https://seodesignchicago.com/seo-blog/what-is-a-google-wildcard-search/), the following wildcards and operators would come in handy:

- The period operator (**.**): this serves as a wildcard for a single character. So searching for `hahmot.mme` (without quotes) should find both "hahmotamme" and "hahmotimme". You may need  to change your Google settings to Finnish (to get Finnish instead of English search results) or add `site:fi` to the search to limit it to resources from Finland. The search results for [`hahmot.mme site:fi`](https://www.google.com/search?q=hahmot.mme+site%3Afi) don't impress me, though.
- The percent symbol (**%**): this replaces one or more characters.
- The underscore (**_**): this represents a single character. The blog post [Complete List of Google Search Operators and How to Use Them](https://www.wincher.com/blog/google-search-operators) describes this as "a wildcard for Google Autocomplete", which is not quite the same thing. Unfortunately, [`hahmot_mme site:fi`](https://www.google.com/search?q=hahmot_mme+site%3Afi&biw=960&bih=901&ei=JiuAYqGhDuyUxc8PvZCLWA&ved=0ahUKEwihzKCTg-D3AhVsSvEDHT3IAgsQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=hahmot_mme+site%3Afi) does not give me any results, unlike the period operator.

The [Google Search Operators List](https://kinsta.com/blog/google-search-operators/#google-search-operators-list) does not list any of the above operators or wildcards and I have not been able to find any [documentation from Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433) about the wildcards I have listed.

Possibly, Google is not the ideal search engine for the type of searches you need. You would be better of with a good search system over a text corpus, but access to such corpora is usually not free of charge. See for example [Finnish text corpora (Sketch Engine)](https://www.sketchengine.eu/corpora-and-languages/finnish-text-corpora/), [International Corpus of Learner Finnish (ICLFI)](http://urn.fi/urn:nbn:fi:lb-20140730163) and those listed by the [Institute for the Languages of Finland](https://www.kotus.fi/en/corpora_and_other_material/about_the_corpora_and_other_material/links_to_electronic_corpora_and_other_material).

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer!

I have used Corpora for English before and I am familiar with the concept. 

I know Estonian language has an inflection synthesized, I am sure Finnish has one too and many other languages.  I am a little surprised that Google hasn't linked up to those.